# Letting a loop run back and forth in Processing

Tags: for-loop, boolean, processing

Currently I am trying to get a loop "running forth and back" in a Processing sketch. I can do it with `mouseY` for example – but I want to have it automatically: the `rect();` should appear horizontally line by line… like 1, 1+next, 1+next+next and after 15 lines reverse! 15, 14, 13, 12,11,10,9…
With `frameCount;` I can let them run down as I want… but not yet back. So I read about boolean statements… and tried to get it in syntax… syntax seems ok… but I can not really get the right logic to make it work. Does someone have an Idea how to really write it in the correct way?
This is my Code so far:

```
int a;
int i;
int step = 60;
void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
for (a = 0; a < 15; a++) {
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  fill(255, 255, 255);
  rect(216*i,60*a,216,60);
}
 
  }
}
```

This creates the pattern – all at once – I know `for (a = 0; a < mouseY; a++)` or `for (a = 0; a < frameCount; a++)` would make it work but I thought to make it automatically this needs to appear somewhere – but how?

```
a+=step;
if ( a > 15 || a < 0 ){
step = -step;
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will probably be easier is you don't try to change the way you increment the steps but rather how many rectangles you generate for each step. To make it more clear consider this code:

```
MAX_RECTANGLES = 15;
let frameCount = 0;

while (frameCount < 100) {
  frameCount++;

  step = frameCount % (MAX_RECTANGLES * 2);
  nbRect = MAX_RECTANGLES - Math.abs(MAX_RECTANGLES - step);

  console.log(step, nbRect);
}
```

The `frameCount` variable and the `while` loop are only recreating the p5js loop, what is interesting here are the `step` and `nbRect` variables:

- `MAX_RECTANGLES` is the number of rectangles you want to show when you show them all. In our example we want to show 15 rectangles.
- `step` will will vary between `0` and `MAX_RECTANGLES * 2` in our example this will vary between `0` and `30`.
- And we will vary `nbRect` between `0` and `15` with the following rules:

  - If `0 <= step <= 15` then `0 <= nbRect <= 15`
  - If `16 <= step <= 30` then `15 >= nbRect >= 0`

Running the code might make it easier to understand. With this mechanism you transform an ever increasing value (`frameCount`) to a value varying between `0` and `15`.

You can have a look at this [p5js codepen](https://codepen.io/statox/pen/zYBQVOX) which does what you want with the method I just described.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you statox! So i wrote it into Processing like this:

```
int MAX_RECT = 18;
int step = 60;

void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
  frameRate(30);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  int step = (frameCount/2 % MAX_RECT) *2;
  int nbRectangles = MAX_RECT - Math.abs(MAX_RECT - step);

  for (int a = 0; a < nbRectangles; a++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fill(255, 255, 255);
      rect(216 * i, 60 * a, 216, 60);
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way not to redraw the first line of rects? I have to check out the Math.abs(); function – I am not yet familiar with this… :-(